# Google Analytics and Internet explorer 6 not working

Tags: internet-explorer, google-analytics, traffic

Hello i have chat windows application using embedded web view using Internet Explorer 6 borowser
but the google analytics is not showing any traffic from this page embedded in the app

i want Google Analytics to read that traffic

here is my code  i am

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'myDomain.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async =     true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') +     '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Comment: A lot of major companies do not support IE6.  [Not even Microsoft will support it anymore](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/end-of-support.aspx) in a few days (they are dropping Win XP support, which means <IE9 will no longer be supported). Neither should you.